# How to pass Parameter value to Instance Variable?

Tags: java, class, variables, parameters, instance

Here are the instructions I have for a class project that I've given up on.

The constructor should call the appropriate set methods of the String class, to assign the values passed as parameters to the instance variables size and toppings

I have a constructor of a Pizza class but it will not keep the parameter values for size and toppings that I pass to it even if I use size = this.size. I don't understand what set method my teacher is referring to. All I need is the conceptual understanding and I will be able to do complete this project.

edit: to be clear, I know my code gives a NPE right now, because my variable toppings is null in toString(), so I'm trying to pass the toppings that has been changed by Pizza() to toString()

```
public class Pizza {

private char size;
private String[] toppings;
private int status;
public final static int NOT_STARTED = 0;
public final static int IN_PROGRESS = 1;
public final static int READY = 2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] testArray = new String[]{"poop", "pee"};
    Pizza newpizza2 = new Pizza('L', testArray);
    System.out.println(newpizza2.toString());
}

//Boolean method with a char parameter that checks the size and sets the char of the pizza size (S,M,L) and returns true. 
public boolean setSize(char size2) {
    if (size2 == 'S'||size2 == 'M'||size2 == 'L') {
        size = size2;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        size = 'M';
        return false;
    }
}

//Boolean method with an int parameter that checks the status and sets the status of the pizza readiness.
public boolean setStatus(int status2) {
    if (status2 >= NOT_STARTED && status2 <= READY) {
        status = status2;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        status = NOT_STARTED;
        return false;
    }
}

//Void method with a String array parameter that only sets the toppings from user input and returns no value. 
public void setToppings(String[] toppings) {
    toppings = this.toppings;
}

//A Get method for setSize to return the value of size.
public char getSize() {
    return this.size;
}

//A Get method for setStatus to return the value of status.
public int getStatus() {
    return this.status;
}
//A Get method for setToppings to return the value of toppings[].
public String[] getToppings() {
    return this.toppings;
}

//Int method that checks the number of toppings and returns the amount of toppings or 0 if there are no toppings given.
public int numToppings() {
    if (toppings != null) {
        return toppings.length;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

//Method that calculates the price of the pizza based on the instance variables and returns the price.
public double calcPrice() {
    if (size == 'S') {
        double price = 8;
        double toppingPrice = toppings.length;
        double total = price + toppingPrice;
        return total;
    }
    else if (size =='M') {
        double price = 9;
        double toppingPrice = 0;
        if (toppings != null) {
            toppingPrice = toppings.length * 1.5;
        }
        double total = price + toppingPrice;
        return total;
    }
    else if (size =='L') {
        double price = 10;
        double toppingPrice = toppings.length * 2;
        double total = price + toppingPrice;
        return total;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
/********************************/
//No argument Constructor//
public Pizza() {
    size = 'M';
    status = NOT_STARTED;
    toppings = null; 
}
public Pizza(char size, String[] toppings) {
    size = this.size;
    System.out.println(toppings.length);
    status = NOT_STARTED;
}
public String statusPhrase() {
    if (status == NOT_STARTED) {
        return "Not Started";
    }
    else if (status == IN_PROGRESS) {
        return "In Progress";
    }
    else {
        return "Ready";
    }
}
public String toString() {
    String combo, combo2 = "", combo3;
    Pizza newpizza = new Pizza();
    newpizza.setSize(size);
    newpizza.setToppings(toppings);
    //Print out the method's return values
    if (toppings.length == 0) {
        combo = "Pizza size " + newpizza.getSize() + ". No toppings.";
    }
    else {
        combo = "Pizza size " + newpizza.getSize() + ". Toppings: ";
    }
    //List the toppings in number order using a for loop
    for (int i = 0; i<=newpizza.numToppings()-1; i++){
        combo2 += "\n" + (i+1)+ ". " + newpizza.getToppings()[i];
    }
    combo3 = "\n"+newpizza.statusPhrase();
    return combo + combo2 + combo3;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple:

```
private char someChar;
public void setSomeChar (char someChar) {
    this.someChar = someCHar; // 'this' refers to THIS instance.
}
```

It is also important to know that the thing on the left site is the one the value gets passed to (excuse my english). 
When you write:

```
private char someChar;
public void setSomeChar (char someChar) {
    someChar = this.someCHar; //
}
```

you pass the value of the instance variable to the local method parameter (they coincidentally have the same name).

To say it a little more generally:

```
private char instanceVariable;

public void someMethod (char someLocalParameter) {
    /* local means that it is only known inside this method. That's why everything 
     *  you assign to it just disappears after executing the method.
     */   

     someLocalParameter = this.instanceVariable // nothing happens

     this.instanceVariable = someLocalParameter // will do the job
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This your current constructor

```
public Pizza(char size, String[] toppings) {
    size = this.size;
    System.out.println(toppings.length);
    status = NOT_STARTED;
}
```

Your constructor should look like this

```
public Pizza(char size, String[] toppings) {
    this.size = size;
    this.toppings = toppings
    System.out.println(toppings.length);
    status = NOT_STARTED;
}
```